# What programmer (tool) can be used to read PIC16C72A?

Tags: microcontroller

I tried a Pickit2 and a Pickit3 but using MPlab IPE, neither of them allow the "connect" button to become available when selecting the PIC16C72A or any of the "C" OTP chips.

Comment: The title should not be the only instance of your question. Please include your question in the body as well.

Comment: The datasheet lists the tools that can be used to program it and thus access the device. If the device has readout protection enabled, like on a commercial product, you can't read the contents.

Answer (score 2):

The current [Microchip Device Support document](https://packs.download.microchip.com/DeviceDoc/Device_Support.pdf) lists the PIC16C72A on page 26.
[image]

As you can see (and from your experience), the PICkit3 & PICkit4 do not support this very old PIC.
The only current hardware listed in this document which does support it is the [MPLAB PM3](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/DV007004).

It's possible that an older PICkit2 or ICD2 would support it (or even a PICstart if you could dredge one up from somewhere), but you'd also have to find older versions of the software too.

You may also have some luck looking for an Arduino or rPI project which implements Microchip's ICSP protocol and could probably read & write an old PIC like this.

Comment: MPLAB 8.92 might be able to access the PICkit2 for this device. When I was still using the PIC16C devices, I used a PICstart. An old PICkit1 might also work if you can find one. And someone on the Microchip forum sells a programmer and software that might work, or which could be "hacked" to work. The ICSD interface is not too complex, and a DIY reader is probably a reasonable project.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I imagine there's quite a few PICSTART Plus programmers gathering dust worldwide (I have at least two of them including one with the rare transparent case). You could try eBay or some other garage sale type venue.

The PRO MATE II and MPLAB PM3 were more professional programmers and will probably attract a much higher price used. If memory serves, the PICSTART Plus was sold as a "development-only programmer" since it did not vary the Vdd during programming/verification.

Answer (score 1):

There are some third party programming tools that claim to be able to interface to the PIC16C72A device. I won't provide a direct link to the product, but if you search for "mcutools" on eBay you should be able to find it.

I searched the Microchip forum for third party programmers and software, and did not find much except a warning that some of these devices can harm and perhaps destroy the PIC, so be careful.

There is at least one "stand-alone" software program that can work with the PICkit3. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBQLf3UErx8) is a video (but I have not watched it).

Ah, here is "[PICkitminus](http://kair.us/projects/pickitminus/)" which is what I was trying to find. Open source and worth a shot.